# Texture not loaded but drawn

Tags: c++, textures, sfml

I'm testing some SFML 2.3 stuff and I see something strange. I load a texture and then apply it to a sprite, the sprite looks good (it has the texture) but in the debug console it says that the texture was not loaded.

This is the code for the main program

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Sprite Test");

    sf::Texture texture;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile("mirror.png"))
    {
        std::cout << "Error loading texture" << std::endl;
    }

    sf::Sprite sprite(texture);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        window.clear();

        window.draw(sprite);

        window.display();
    }
}
```

And this are the outputs:

[image: Console]

[image: Window]

As you can see the sprite has the texture but the console says that the texture was not loaded :/ I don't know if is a bug of the 2.3 version of SFML or is my computer problem, i'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I've included all the include/libs folder and also add the dependencies to the linker
Thanks in advance for all who will answer me

Comment: mind your semicolons

Comment: doh! taht was an error related to a previous test, anyway removing that semicolons doesn't change the result

Comment: See: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/issues/880